# How to recursively combine pairs of elements from a list?

Tags: python

I am attempting to deduplicate some pandas DataFrames, and I have a function that does this pair-wise (i.e. two dfs at a time). I want to write another function that takes a list of DataFrames of arbitrary length and combines the first two elements in the list, then combines the result with the third element in the list until we reach the end of the list.

For simplicity, I'll assume my deduplication function is simply string concatenation.

I tried some recursive functions, but it's not quite correct.

```py
def dedupe_recursive(input_list):
    if input_list == []:
        return 
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(input_list)-1):
            new_list = input_list[i+1:]
            deduped = dedupe(new_list[i], new_list[i+1])
            print(deduped, new_list)
            return dedupe_recursive(new_list)
```

Input (list): `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Output (list of lists): `[['ab'], ['ab', 'c'], ['abc', 'd']]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function for exactly this kind of thing, it's called [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). You would use it like this:

```
from functools import reduce

final_df = reduce(dedupe, list_of_dataframes)
```